# JQuery Callback working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just started learning JQuery from w3schools .. I just want to learn the basic syntax.
I am a little confused with [this piece of code](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_callback):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
    $("#btn1").click(function()
    {
        $("#test1").text(function(a, origText)
        {
            i = (parseInt(i)+1);
            return "Old text: " + origText + " New text: Hello world! (index: " + i + ")";
        });
    });
});
```

I understand the usage of callback in javascript but I dont understand how it works here.

this function(a, origText )
where a = i think this is index .. but its always 0
and origText = the current original text from the element "test1"
I have not declared any such function. I am not sure if its available in "jquery-2.0.3.js" file.

I cant understand how when I click the btn1 for the first time, origText contains test1 elements current value?

I know this might be a really stupid question to ask .. but I tried using my head and wasn't quiet able to understand. My only guess would be its a predefined function in the jquery-2.0.3.js file i am using but I just wanted to be sure.

Thanks in advance :)

Update:
I promise I wont be using any more references from w3schools after this one .. I was in hurry .. just wanted to get myself acquainted with the syntax so was going through the examples. Didnt understand this one so asked.

Comment: [Required reading material.](http://www.w3fools.com)  Also, you should learn jquery from [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/), not w3schools.. unless its a good book or something.

Comment: Start here http://jqfundamentals.com/

Comment: Yes Daedalus, jason I agree w3schools isnt the best place to learn anything .. But i just wanted to do a initial quick study before I sleep off tonight, will start reading from more credible sources from tomm :)

Comment: @RahulDabas As to your question, the [documentation for the `.text()` method explains it best](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text).

Comment: You slipped it into your comment with so much class that I missed it :). Kudos to you for not responding with the nerdy exhale and eye roll that overtakes me every time I read "w3school.com"

Comment: @Daedalus .. thank you so much .. I can now sleep peacefully .. If you would copy that comment into an answer .. I will be able to accept this as the correct answer .. thanks agn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As may be seen from the documentation for the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) method of jQuery, when an anonymous function is passed in as an argument to the method, the anonymous function is passed two arguments, the first being the index of the element in the set of the elements the method is called on, and the second being the original text content of the element in question.

Whatever this anonymous function returns, jQuery uses to set the text content of the element in question.

[Here is a small demo demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/3jVgS/).